# understanding geb content DSL "to"

Tags: groovy, geb

I am trying to understand geb content DSL but the use of `to` is not clear to me as described [here](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/pages.html#to). If the link is clicked, then it would go to a page where the link will take it. Why would we want it to go to a different page by specifying `to`. Or do we specify `to`, only so the code can check that a particular page has been reached.

Or I am missing something here , can someone please comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between telling geb to go somewhere (`to(Page)`) and declaring in the content, that this link will end up at some Page.  This already can fire some asserts etc.

See the code from the doc:

```
class ExamplePage extends Page {
    static content = {
        helpLink(to: HelpPage) { $("a", text: "Help") }
//              ~~~~~ we want to end up at HelpPage
    }
}

class HelpPage extends Page {}

Browser.drive {
    to ExamplePage
// ~~~~ Please go to ExamplePage
    helpLink.click()
    assert page.class == HelpPage
}
```

Comment: Also, using `to:` means that you don't have to tell Geb which page it needs to switch it's state to after clicking particular content - it will switch the page for you automatically. The html page is not the same thing as Geb's page - the latter allows you to use content definitions specified for a particular page and define methods for interacting with these definitions. Going to an url is not the same as switching Geb page and switching Geb page (the `page` property of `geb.Browser` instance) will not change the url of the browser you're driving (unless it is done using `to()` or `via()`).

Comment: @cfrick Thank you. That clears my doubt. I can see now how it can be useful.